# How to find the Sum or Total of a Listbox

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a listbox that has two columns of date entered into it using the code:

```
   'Press  to place value into Array
    Private Sub TxtMark_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TxtMark.KeyDown


    Dim Mark As Double
    Dim DataString As String

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        If Double.TryParse(TxtMark.Text, Mark) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show(" You must enter a numeric value like 1 or 2")
            TxtMark.Clear()
            TxtMark.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Mark < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Valid range is between 0 and 100, 7 would work " _
                & Mark.ToString & " Does not")
            TxtMark.Clear()
            TxtMark.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If



        If NumberOfScores < MaxEntries Then
            ScoreArray(NumberOfScores) = Mark

            DataString = (NumberOfScores + 1).ToString + ".  " + _
                NameArray(NumberOfScores).PadRight(15) + _
  Mark.ToString.PadLeft(5)
            Lstdisplay.Items.Add(DataString)
            NumberOfScores += 1
        End If
        TxtMark.Clear()
        TxtName.Clear()
        TxtName.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    End If
```

What I want to do is have a label that does the some of the Mark automatically as the data is entered. Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to iterate through all entries and add up the values:

```
    Dim total As Double
    For Each s As String In ListBox1.Items
        total+= s.substring(...)
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("The total is:" + total.ToString)
```

The tricky part is extracting the numeric value from the string.

But it would be much easier if you placed the data into a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control. With the values all in one column. Then you don't need to do the substring to extract the numeric values out

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to add a custom extension that returns the numeric part of the string and then use Matt Wilko's iteration as above.

To create a custom extension add a class to your project as follows:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Namespace Extensions
Public Module ExtensionMethods
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function GetNumeric(ByVal source As String) As String
        'Takes the passed in string and returns the numeric part
        Dim ReturnString As String = ""
        For A = 1 To source.Length
            If IsNumeric(source.Substring(A, 1)) Then
                ReturnString += source.Substring(A, 1)
            End If
        Next
        Return ReturnString
    End Function

End Module
End Namespace
```

If you then import MyProject.Extensions on you project you can use string.GetNumeric to return the numeric part of your code.

Hope this helps you (and others).